# Setting a data from jquery to show in select in HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have a select option to select the year.

Year is have to set by jquery ajax code as below.(This data is retrieved by the db. Shows as 2015).

If jquery value is null have to show current year.

**My code:**

**HTML:**

```
    <?php
year : <select name="from_year" id="from_year" class="select">
<?php 
$year_now = date('Y');
for ($i = 0; $i < 149; $i++) { 
    $year = date('Y') - $i;     
echo "<option value= " . $year . ">" . $year . "</option>"; 
}
    }
    ?>
    </select>
```

**JQUERY**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#selected_tab2").click(function(){
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url:'<?php echo site_url('myfile/settings_screen'); ?>',
            data:{tab_id:'2'},
            success: function(data){
                var split_value = data.split(",");
                $("#from_year select").val(split_value[15]); // split_value[15] shows 2015 when printed by a alert.
            }
        }
    });
```

Please Help me to do this.

Comment: where is your <option> tag code and values in <select> tag ?

Comment: can you provide the html of the `myfile/ettings_screen` page?

Comment: @madalinivascu data is passing fine .I printed the data. It shows all.

Comment: @tenten what is the role of the ajax call??

Comment: `url:'<?php echo site_url(\'myfile/settings_screen\'); ?>',` quotes should be escaped.

Comment: @madalinivascu I just want to apply `split_value(15)` to id `from_year'. I tried this like above. But not applying right. That's what i want to clear here.

Comment: what is this split_value(15) function, where does the 15 come from?

Comment: @madalinivascu `data` is coming from echoing in path `myfile/settings_screen` in the controller. I'm splitting `data` here and year comes under `split_value(15) `. `data` is like `12,15,17, ` etc.

Comment: can you provide the code from `myfile/settings_screen`, why aren't you sending the correct date from there

Comment: @tenten  are you tell data is 12,15,17 , that 15th index value ? how ? use & check console.log(split_value);

Comment: Just to make sure: Is that jQuery code inside your .php file or seperate? Because you can't use PHP in .js files.

Answer (score 0):

The selector you used below is wrong

```
$("#from_year select").val(split_value[15]);
```

You can use one of them below,

```
$("select#from_year").val(split_value[15]);
```

OR

```
$("#from_year").val(split_value[15]);
```

I have given here a sample js fiddle and compare with your code as I am not sure the value of `split_value[15`.

https://jsfiddle.net/balasuar/atg5m6ym/7468/

Comment: @tenten, can you tell me whats the value of `split_value[15]`?

Comment: @tenten, check the working fiddle at, `https://jsfiddle.net/balasuar/atg5m6ym/7468/`

Comment: split_value[15] value is 2015. I have mentioned it in the question.

Comment: @tenten print console.log(split_value); check the values

Answer (score 0):

First `site_url(\'myfile/settings_screen\');` should be escaped.

> If jquery value is null have to show current year.

```
 if(!split_value[15])$("#from_year select").val(new Date().getFullYear());
 else $("#from_year select").val(split_value[15]);
```

or

```
$("#from_year select").val(split_value[15] || new Date().getFullYear());
```

Your example

```
year : <select name="from_year" id="from_year" class="select">

     <?php
     $year_now = date('Y');
     for ($i=0 ; $i < 149; $i++) {
     $year = date('Y') - $i;
     echo "<option value='" . $year . "'>" . $year . "</option>";
      }
      }
      ?>
            </select>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $("#selected_tab2").click(function(){
                  $.ajax({
                     type: "POST",
                     url:'<?php echo site_url(\'myfile/settings_screen\'); ?>',
                        data:{tab_id:'2'},
                        success: function(data){
                            var split_value = data.split(",");
                            $("#from_year select").val(split_value[15] || new Date().getFullYear()); // split_value[15] shows 2015 when printed by a alert.
                        }
                    }
                });
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `$("#from_year select")` to `$("select#from_year")`